# How to remove one element from array after explode

Tags: sql, arrays, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a table with column id_list in which there are a set of strings e.g. `["1","2","4","6"]`.

The original table is

```
+-------------------+
|   id_list         |
+-------------------+
| ["1","2","4","6"] |
|-------------------+
| ["1","2","4","6"] |
|-------------------+
| ["1","2","4","6"] |
|-------------------+
| ["1","2","4","6"] |
|-------------------+
| ["7"]             |
|-------------------+
```

I created the following table by explode the id_list column:

```
SELECT id, id_list FROM data LATERAL VIEW explode(id_list) dummy AS id;
```

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|     id      |   id_list         |
+-------------+-------------------+
|      1      | ["1","2","4","6"] |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      2      | ["1","2","4","6"] |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      4      | ["1","2","4","6"] |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      6      | ["1","2","4","6"] |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      7      | ["7"]             |
+-------------|-------------------+
```

I want to remove the id from the id_list to have a table like below:

```
+-------------+-------------------+
|     id      |   id_list         |
+-------------+-------------------+
|      1      | ["2","4","6"]     |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      2      | ["1","4","6"]     |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      4      | ["1","2","6"]     |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      6      | ["1","2","4"]     |
+-------------|-------------------+
|      7      | []                |
+-------------|-------------------+
```

How to do that without using UDF?

Comment: @leftjoin, sorry for the confusion. The id column is the exploded array from id_list, I just kept the array with the exploded elements. In other words, id "1", "2", "4", "6" are from the exploded array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explode and collect only those elements which are not equal id.

Demo:

```
with initial_data as (
select 1 id   ,array("1","2","4","6") list union all
select 2   ,array("1","2","4","6") list union all    
select 3   ,array("1","2","4","6")   list union all 
select 4  ,array("1","2","4","6")   list union all 
select 6   ,array("1","2","4","6")   list union all
select 7   ,array("7")  
)    


SELECT d.id, collect_list(case when e.id!= d.id then e.id end) id_list
  FROM initial_data d 
       LATERAL VIEW explode(list) e AS id
 GROUP BY d.id;
```

Result:

```
OK
id      id_list
1       ["2","4","6"]
2       ["1","4","6"]
3       ["1","2","4","6"]
4       ["1","2","6"]
6       ["1","2","4"]
7       []
Time taken: 38.645 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

Comment: Thanks@leftjoin. I have modified the original question.

Comment: I think you answered my question. I just need to explode one more time. By the way, I think ```GROUP BY d.id``` should be appended in the original query.